# LaTeX - full width row on a tabular - cell occupying multiple cells

Tags: latex, cell, tabular

I am trying to recreate this table on Latex:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6QOv.png
but I can't figure out how to have a cell occupying three cells instead of just one (for the Tritanomaly percentage entry for example).

This is the best that I've been able to do so far:

```
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
{\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{gray!0}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\hline
\backslashbox{CVD}{Sex}
&Male&Female&\textbf{Any}\\\hline\hline
Deuteranomaly & 5\% & 0.35\% & 2.68\% \\\hline
Deuteranopia & 1\% & 0.1\% & 0.56\% \\\hline
Protanomaly & 1.08\% & 0.03\% & 0.55\% \\\hline
Protanopia & 1.01\% & 0.01\% & 0.51\% \\\hline
Tritanomaly* &&  0.02\% & \\ \hline
Tritanopia* && 0.01\% &\\\hline
Monochromacy* && 0.0001\% &\\\hline
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{8.12}\% & \textbf{0.52}\% & \textbf{4.32}\% \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: you're probably looking for `\multicolumn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\multicolumn` is your new best friend:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{gray!0}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
\hline
\backslashbox{CVD}{Sex}
&Male&Female&\textbf{Any}\\\hline\hline
Deuteranomaly & 5\% & 0.35\% & 2.68\% \\\hline
Deuteranopia & 1\% & 0.1\% & 0.56\% \\\hline
Protanomaly & 1.08\% & 0.03\% & 0.55\% \\\hline
Protanopia & 1.01\% & 0.01\% & 0.51\% \\\hline
Tritanomaly* & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.02\%} \\ \hline
Tritanopia* &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.02\%}\\\hline
Monochromacy* &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.02\%}\\\hline
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{8.12}\% & \textbf{0.52}\% & \textbf{4.32}\% \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]